# NextJS URL rewrite from index to different URI not working

Tags: next.js, vercel

I would like to do a URL rewrite, so when I go to `/` it will keep the URL but redirects to `/some-other-page`.

My attempt is as follows in my `next.config.js`:

```
 async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/",
        destination: "/some-other-page",
      },
    ];
  },
```

But it would not work. Neither on my local, nor on Vercel. I am on latest Next 11 version.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue, just delete `index.tsx` from your pages folder